# Clojure: Controlling compilation options via Leiningen

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Can I control compiler options (optimizations, generation of debug info and so on) via Leiningen (project file)?

Is `javac` involved at some point or JVM code emitted by directly Clojure compiler? I want to make my uberjar as small and fast as possible.

Another close question is `jvm-options`. I am not familiar with Java, but seems like they make sense in case of run by Leiningen (via `lein run`) because uberjar executed directly by JVM and I control it's options: `java -client <other options> -jar uberapp_uberjar.jar`

Doc says I can use profiles. On my mac I can't find profile fiels in `~/.lein/`. There is `show-profiles` command, is there command to show a profile?

Comment: Clojure isn't compiled, it's interpreted. The Clojure compiler only generates classes in specific cases when you tell it to (usually for Java interop).

Comment: DaoWen, this is incorrect. Clojure code is compiled into JVM bytecode: http://clojure.org/compilation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a whole range of options you can set in the leiningen project.clj file, and java options of all sorts is part of this.

When I need to see what is possible I always look at this project.clj sample file on github

https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj

I believe he have been relative good at keeping it up to date

Comment: Yes, thank you! I can add `-g:none`. Also I can use general JVM approaches as `pack200` and ProGuard.

Answer (score 3):

:javac-options can take any [javac option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options).

For example:

```
(defproject com.example.foo/bar "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description
"Some awesome app."

:url "http://www.example.com"
:license {:name "" :url ""}
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
               [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]]

:aot [com.example.foo.core]
:main com.example.foo.core
:target-dir "target/"
:source-paths ["src"]
:compile-path "target/classes"
:javac-options ["-target" "1.6" "-source" "1.6" "-Xlint:-options" "-g"])
```

Comment: I noticed that. I tried `:javac-options ["-g:none"]` and `debug:false` but my jar's size didn't change - I added new profile `opt` with these options and ran command `lein with-profile opt uberjar`. Thanks for pointing out it here.

Answer (score 0):

The comment DaoWen posted is incorrect.

Clojure code is compiled on the fly into JVM bytecode as [can be seen here](http://clojure.org/compilation).

As for your question, you can pass JVM options to leiningen in the project.clj file:

```
(defproject example "0.0.1"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
  :jvm-opts ["-javaagent:newrelic/newrelic.jar"]})
```